# How to make my particles go backwards?

Tags: animation, particles

I created a particle system based on *quick effects > quick explode* and modified some parameters (like poly count and gravity) on the particle system tab.  And as you can see in the image, I made a word that explodes from its center. The only problem I have now is the direction of the particles. The object currently breaks apart from left to right, is there any way I can make the object break apart from right to left (as in the diagram below the screenshot)?

[image]

**Video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/as751siajpqetsc/clip0003.avi?dl=0**

Comment: No that I know of . . . If you explode it from right to left, you can play the video backwards and it will look like it is being built from Left to Right.

Comment: No. lol it will make them reassemble. @beavoru try using wind forces.

Comment: I applied the Wind forces, but it didnt work :/

Comment: @VinceScalia Isn't that what he wanted? ". . . fill the word . . ."?

Comment: @beavoru Do you want to explode or reassemble the word?

Comment: Not this time, after this i can reverse the sequence in another editing software, yet, the thing i need is to make the particles start appearing from the left, in other words, on Blender i need the particles to start exploding from the right side of the word.
But that's the question :/

Comment: I need to explode it for now because i can reverse the sequence on After Effects, so it's no problem, yet i did that but the word start creating itself starting from the right side, not left, so it looks weird, that's why i need here on Blender make the explosion start from right, not left

Comment: @beavoru could you invert your text (scale by -1 along x), apply your _quick explode_, then mirror the the renders along x in the compositor? (yeah, super hacky..)

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/all-tutorials/394-tutorial-dissolve-your-logo-in-blender-262.html)

Comment: Thank you, i tried the scale but it didn't work, and about the tutorial, even though it works to dissolve the model, i only need to use this effect as a request, so i'm trying to figure out how to 'invert' the direction of the particles :/

Comment: I uploaded a video here, as you can see if i revert this animation on and editing software it will begin to apear from the right side to the left, but what i want it's the same backwards...o i need the model' exploding' from right to left :/
https://www.dropbox.com/s/as751siajpqetsc/clip0003.avi?dl=0